# Gradle Jar Creating Task getting stucked

Tags: reactjs, gradle, intellij-idea, gradle-task

I am new to gradle. When running the gradle build task in intelliJ, my task keep running infinitely and never completed. The task is written as follows:

```
task webjar(type: Jar) {
    from(fileTree("build")) {  
        into "META-INF/resources"
    } 
}
jar.finalizedBy('webjar')
```

Can anybody help me in pointing out if I am doing anything wrong here?

**update**: When i am writing the task as follows it finishes successfully:

```
task webjar(type: Jar) {
    destinationDir file("${projectDir}/build")
    from(fileTree("build")) {  
        into "META-INF/resources"
    } 
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to pack all the files in the temporary `build` directory into a `.jar` file? I would guess that some files in the directory are locked by Gradle during the execution, mainly the files regarding the current task.

Comment: @lukas what should be the correct task.Its a react app.

Comment: @LukasKörfer how should i fix that

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are attempting to pack the whole `build` folder into that jar, which includes *all* the project output.

So that is most likely the issue there. `build` should not be what you package in `META-INF/resources`.

Instead you will need to identify which task produces the content to be included in `META-INF/resources` and use its output as the `from` argument.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but the same project successfully gets built on windows machine.I am facing this issue on Ubuntu.

Comment: Still pretty sure you do not want to have the whole `build` content in there. So instead of focusing on the difference between platforms, I would fix the root cause and better select what needs to land inside `META-INF/resources`

Comment: Other thing is when i am adding one more field in the above task     destinationDir file("${projectDir}/build")  then I am able to build the jar successfully.

Comment: Can you explain with a small example how can i achieve the same using the previous task output